# How to say in one word about object being referred to?

Tags: single-word-requests

In programming there is a term "reference" which means that the first object refers to the second object. How can I name the second object in one word?

At first, I remembered about forms like "employer" - "employee", but "referer" - "referee" doesn't work, since the referee means something very different.

Comment: these 'computer' questions are always tricky and seem to me to best be posted on said forums.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your programming variable 'a' is a *reference* to an object 'B', then 'B' can be called the *referent* (a term borrowed from the field of linguistics).

> **referent** *noun*
>   The thing in the world that a word or phrase denotes or stands for.
>   ‘‘the Morning Star’ and ‘the Evening Star’ have the same referent (the planet Venus)’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/referent)

Answer (score 2):

*Referee* (/rɛˈfəriː/), as the word for a sports official, and *referee* (/rɛfəˈriː/), as the word for something that has been referred, are pronounced differently. The former has stress on the first *e* while the latter has stress on the second *e*. So there *is* a distinction and you could absolutely use the word to describe the second object.

That said, *reference* is actually a great word itself and is widely used in most programming languages involving objects.

> Object *b* is **a reference** of object *a*.

Another word that might be acceptable here is *child* if you're referring to classical inheritance with objects.